# Excel VBA for linking Hyperlink formula in a cell to a Macro

Tags: excel

I Have a long list of hyperlink formulas in column B.  Below is an example of the formula inside a cell.  What i want to achieve is when i click a hyperlink in any rows of the whole column B, It will run also a separate single VBA Macro.

=HYPERLINK("#SHEET1!D"&ROW(D2066),D2066)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)`
event but I don't think it will work with a hyperlink formula. Possibly a selection_change event would work in this case.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        If Left(Target.Formula, 10) = "=HYPERLINK" Then
            MsgBox "My Code here"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This would go in the worksheet module.

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dave for your quick response, appreciate it very much since i really need help on this.  Actually my vba macro is just a single line as below:

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        If Left(Target.Formula, 10) = "=HYPERLINK" Then
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Comment: Sorry, this is my very first post here, whenever i click enter, my comment already posts in the forum.  The above code i posted does not work either Dave.

Comment: i got it to work, thank you very much.  It is a list of hyperlinks to another worksheet.  I am using it on two windows of the same workbook.  When i click the hyperlink, it takes me to the referenced cell, then the code continues to scroll  the active cell to top. i do it on 2 monitors where both sheets of the same workbook are open.   My follow up question is, when i click the hyperlink, the focus becomes the other sheet.  I would like to have to focus still on the sheet with the hyperlink.  Thank you.

Comment: Dave, no worries, all i need is your initial code of selectionchange.   Thank you very much once again.